# JasperReports Vs iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I need a reporting capability in my web application. I have googled the net and found that JasperReports is the best Java reporting framework out there.

I wanted to learn about JasperReports but when I went to their site, I found out also about iReport.

I checked at the download site and it says.
**If you're interested in JasperReports, particularly if this is your first download, we recommend that you may want to consider downloading iReport instead. The iReport download includes JasperReports.**

Does this mean that I should learn iReport instead? Or which is which.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

iReport is a graphical tool for creating jasper reports.

It will generate the xml jasper report file for you.

Or to quote iReport:

> iReport is a visual report designer
>   for JasperReports. The library is a
>   report engine that can be integrated
>   in your open or commercial application
>   to generate the reports designed with
>   iReport, display them on screen or
>   export them in a final format like
>   PDF, OpenOffice, DOCX and many others.
>   Alternatively, you can stream the
>   result through a web application or
>   send the final document directly to a
>   printer. JasperReports is in some way
>   the core of iReport.

After you create your file you will have to learn a small bit about Jasper report to integrate it into your program.

For more information have a look at this iReport [introduction page](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-designer-getting-started).

Answer (score 4):

Report templates used in JasperReports are written in special XML-based language. XML means that these templates are regular text files and may be edited in any text editor. Sometimes it's much more simple to quickly open a template in text editor and make the fix rather than start iReports, open template in it, and do the work moving the mouse.

iReport is effective if one need modify a lot of report elements at once, say move 100 elements by 5 points to left. If only one element should be modified, I often use text editor.

iReport is platform-independent because it is written in Java. I'm successfully using it on Debian Linux and MS Windows XP.

Answer (score 3):

iReport is the visual designer for JasperReport. So, you would need to learn iReport also in order to design a JasperReport.

Answer (score 0):

Ireport is a tool for generating JasperReport.In Ireport there are many graphical options for generating  a good look reports.

It has many templates with different purpose for creating a report. The JasperReport XML based and easily editable by any normal text editor.And JasperReport uses Java or Groovy language.